# How to display currency on Google charts line chart?

Tags: javascript, charts

I am trying to display currency as the Y axis data in a Google API line chart:

[image: Google line chart example]

In the Y axis, I want the numbers to be shown as $0.00, $4.00, $8.00, $12.00, $16.00.

Here is the code I'm using to populate the chart:

```
function drawDailySales() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

            ['Date', 'Daily Sales'],

            <?php foreach ($daily_sales as $date => $sales) {

                echo "['".$date."', {v: ".$sales['Amount'].", f: '$".number_format($sales['Amount'], 2, '.', ',')."'}],";   

            } ?>

            ]);

            var options = {
                title: 'Daily Sales',
                legend: { 
                    position: 'bottom' 
                }

            };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('daily_sales'));

        chart.draw(data, options);

    }
```

This works on the tooltip that displays when the mouse is hovered over a point on the chart, but it doesn't display as currency in the Y axis on the chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding `vAxis.ticks` to your options, from the [Configuration Options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options)?

As such...

`vAxis: { ticks: [{v:0, f:'$0.00'}, {v:4, f:'$4.00'}, ...] }`

Answer (score 2):

**11/2020 Update (another solution)**

Try adding `vAxis: {format: 'currency'}` to your `options` like this:

```
var options = {
  vAxis: {format: 'currency'}
};
```